# Where do the forumlas for expectation and variance for geometric and Poisson distributions come from?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Okay so I have been given a list of 4 distributions and their respective mean(expected) and variance. I can see where the Bernoulli and Binomial ones come from using the definition of expectation and variance, but I can't see why these 2 results are necessarily correct.

If $X$ is distributed Geometric then $E(X)=\frac{1}{p}$, $Var(X)=\frac{1-p}{p^2}$ ($P$ is success probability obviously.)

And...

If $X$ is distributed by Poisson then $E(X)=\lambda$, $Var(X)=\lambda$ ($\lambda$ is average for a given time I think.)

Can anyone explain why this should be the case.

Try and keep it digestible as I'm relatively new to this and don't want to get further confused.

Thanks!

Comment: You can compute both using the definition of expectation and variance (for discrete random variables on integers, $\mathbb{E} X = \sum_{n=0}^\infty n \Pr[X=n]$ and $\mathrm{var} X = \mathbb{E}[X^2] - \mathbb{E}[X]^2 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty n^2 \Pr[X=n] - \mathbb{E}[X]^2$. In either case, the computation is not difficult, given the expression of $\Pr[X=n]$.

Answer (score 0):

For the case of $X$ being Poisson with parameter $\lambda$, the expectation is 
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E} X = \sum_{n=0}^\infty n \mathbb{P}\{X=n\} 
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty n e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^n}{n!}
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty n e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^n}{n!}
= \lambda \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} \\
&= \lambda \sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^{k}}{k!} = \lambda\cdot 1 = \lambda
\end{align}
$$
using the fact that $1 = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \mathbb{P}\{X=k\} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^{k}}{k!}$.

Variance is the same sort of computation, only a tad more complex: since $\operatorname{Var} X = \mathbb{E}[X^2] - (\mathbb{E} X)^2$ and we already known the second term, it is sufficient to compute $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$. Now,

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E} [ X  ^2] \sum_{n=0}^\infty n^2 \mathbb{P}\{X=n\} 
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty n^2 e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^n}{n!}
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2 e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^n}{n!}
= \lambda \sum_{n=1}^\infty n e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} \\
&= \lambda \sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1)e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^{k}}{k!} \\
&= \lambda \left( \sum_{k=0}^\infty ke^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^{k}}{k!} 
+ \sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^{k}}{k!} \right) \\
&= \lambda(\lambda+1)\\
\end{align}
$$
where we used at some point our previous computation that $\mathbb{E}[X]=\lambda$, after recognizing that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty ke^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^{k}}{k!} = \mathbb{E}[X]$ (and that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^{k}}{k!} =1$). Putting it together,
$$\operatorname{Var} X = \mathbb{E}[X^2] - (\mathbb{E} X)^2 = \lambda(\lambda+1) - \lambda^2 = \lambda.$$

For the Geometric distribution, it is the same sort of computations and manipulations, using the explicit formula/definitions of expectation and variance.

Comment: Great answer!!!